# convert python list of list into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists in python that I need to convert to json dictionary. The list is as follows:

```
[
  ['[{"name":"david","level":"k","xaxis":[[]],"yaxis":[[]],', '"count":[[2011, 6], [2012, 0], [2013, 11]]},'],

 ['{"name":"marshall","level":"n","xaxis":[[]],"yaxis":[[]],', 
 '"count":[[2008, 130], [2009, 53], [2010, 10], [2011, 17], [2012, 0], [2013, 142]]}]']
]
```

What I need it to be is:

```
{
 [

  {
   "name": "david", 
   "level": "k", 
   "xaxis": [[]], 
   "yaxis": [[]], 
   "count":[[2011, 6], [2012, 0], [2013, 11]]
    },

  {
   "name": "diana", 
   "level": "k", 
   "xaxis": [[]], 
   "yaxis": [[]], 
   "count":[[2011, 6], [2012, 0], [2013, 11]]
   }

  ]
}
```

So basically, it would be a dictionary containing sub lists, and each sub list having a single dictionary. How it can be achieved with what I have?

**UPDATING:**

So, let me break it down into steps for the purpose of clarity. I need the data structure to be like this (that I am dumping into a .json file):

```
[{
"name": "David",
"level": "s",
"xaxis": [
    []
],
"yaxis": [
    []
],
"count": [
    [2008, 128],
    [2009, 51],
    [2010, 10],
    [2011, 17],
    [2012, 0],
    [2013, 142]
]
  }, {
"name": "Diana",
"level": "v",
"xaxis": [
    []
],
"yaxis": [
    []
],
"count": [
    [2008, 11],
    [2009, 0],
    [2010, 1],
    [2011, 2],
    [2012, 0],
    [2013, 6]
]
}]
```

So the way I am constructing this is as follows:

First I have two lists-> names and calculations:

```
names = ['David', 'Diana']

calculations = [[[2011, 6], [2012, 0], [2013, 11]], [[2008, 130], [2009, 53], [2010, 10], [2011, 17], [2012, 0], [2013, 142]]]
```

Where 'calculations' is a list of lists of lists.

From these two lists, I am creating the initially mentioned structure as follows:

```
import random
from compiler.ast import flatten

names_final = []
calculations_final = []
completed = []

for a in names:
    names_final.append('{"name":"'.encode('utf-8')+a.encode('utf-8')+'","level":"'.encode('utf-8')+random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz').encode('utf-8')+'","xaxis":[[]],"yaxis":[[]],'.encode('utf-8'))

for b in calculations:
    calculations_final.append('"count":'.encode('utf-8')+str(b).encode('utf-8')+'},'.encode('utf-8'))

for i,j in map(None, names_final, calculations_final):
    completed.append(flatten([i,j]))
```

Then finally to the completed list, I am doing following modifications so as to get what I need:

```
completed[0][0]='['+completed[0][0]

completed[-1][-1]= completed[-1][-1][:-1]
completed[-1][-1]=completed[-1][-1]+']'
```

This results in output list mentioned at the top most part of this question. What I need is to convert this into a json object so that it can be viewed over a browser as json object, based on the query defined by the user. I hope this will clarify. What do you guys suggest?

Comment: Your suggested output isn't a valid JSON object, or a valid Python dict. (It _is_ a valid Python set, but I don't think that's what you wanted.) A dictionary doesn't just contain values; it contains mappings from keys to values.

Comment: You are right. I need to convert it into a json object.

Comment: Well, that's not a valid JSON object, so show us what JSON object you _actually_ want to get.

Comment: This smells very strongly of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe if you tell us where you're getting this garbage input from, we can tell you how to read it correctly instead of trying to fix it up after the fact. Or, if you tell us what you're intending to do with it, we can tell you how to get what you actually need instead of the impossible thing you asked for.

Comment: @abarnert I am updating my question for you to suggest about how can I convert this into a json object.

Comment: updated the question..please check.

Comment: OK… Why are you manually building JSON fragments in the first place? Just build the object you want, then `json.dumps` it. And why are you using a deprecated and undocumented module just to flatten things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to turn your list of lists of JSON-encoded things into a list of lists of whatever objects those JSON-encoded things decode to, that's easy:

```
decoded = [[json.loads(value) for value in inner_list] for inner_list in outer_list]
```

And if you want to turn that back into one big JSON-encoded thing, that's easy too:

```
encoded = json.dumps(decoded)
```

If you also want to turn that outer list into a dict (which will encode to a JSON object)… well, that doesn't make sense. You can't just have a dict (or object) containing lists, you have to have a dict *mapping keys to those lists*.

---

On top of that, your input data isn't even a list of lists of valid JSON-encoded things; it's a list of lists of un-decodable JSON fragments. For example, this fragment:

```
"count":[[2011, 6], [2012, 0], [2013, 11]]}
```

… doesn't map to anything.

Maybe what you want is something like this:

```
rejoined = ''.join(''.join(inner_list) for inner_list in outer_list)
decoded = json.loads(rejoined)
```

That will give you this:

```
[{'count': [[2011, 6], [2012, 0], [2013, 11]],
  'level': 'k',
  'name': 'david',
  'xaxis': [[]],
  'yaxis': [[]]},
 {'count': [[2008, 130],
            [2009, 53],
            [2010, 10],
            [2011, 17],
            [2012, 0],
            [2013, 142]],
  'level': 'n',
  'name': 'marshall',
  'xaxis': [[]],
  'yaxis': [[]]}]
```

You can then re-JSON-encode that, or just use `rejoined` as-is (because it's obviously going to be equivalent).

---

Now that you've explained a bit more… you're making things a whole lot harder on yourself than they need to be. There are a number of problems with your code:

- You're trying to build JSON-encoded strings by string manipulation. This is very hard to do, and completely unnecessary. Just construct the object you want, and call `json.dumps` on it. Whenever possible, manipulate *objects*, not their string representations.
- You're `encode`-ing dozens of strings along the way (and missing a few of them!) instead of just building up a big result string and calling `encode` once. Plus, the strings you're calling `encode` on are `str` byte strings, not `unicode` strings, so it doesn't even make sense. Finally, `json.dumps` prefers `unicode` strings (and does the encoding for you), so you don't need to do this at all. In general, do your encoding and decoding as close to the edge as possible, rather than all throughout your code.
- You're trying to create two complex parallel data structures and then zip them together, when you could have just zipped the inputs together. If you can't figure out how to patch things together at the end, you were probably using the wrong data structure in the middle.
- You're using deprecated and undocumented features like `compiler.ast.flatten` and `map` with a `None` function when there are perfectly good ways to do the same things—although they're not actually necessary here anyway. Don't write Python 1.5 code unless you really need to work with Python 1.5.

Here's a much simpler way to write your code:

```
completed = []

for name, calculation in zip(names, calculations):
    completed.append({'name': name, 
                      'level': random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
                      'xaxis': [[]],
                      'yaxis': [[]],
                      'count': calculation})

result = json.dumps(completed)
```

Now `completed` is your data structure, and `result` is a JSON encoding of that data structure. And the problem you were asking for help with doesn't even arise. (And you may not even need `result`; many web service/RPC/etc. libraries let you just pass objects around and automatically JSON-ify them for you.)

Comment: ..thank you for this explanation. It works totally fine. I appreciate your kindness and will be following the tips you mentioned. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have fragments of a JSON string, that when joined together will be valid JSON, you just need to join all of the strings together and pass the result to `json.loads()`:

```
data = [['[{"name":"david","level":"k","xaxis":[[]],"yaxis":[[]],',
         '"count":[[2011, 6], [2012, 0], [2013, 11]]},'],
        ['{"name":"marshall","level":"n","xaxis":[[]],"yaxis":[[]],',
         '"count":[[2008, 130], [2009, 53], [2010, 10], [2011, 17], [2012, 0], [2013, 142]]}]']
       ]

>>> decoded = json.loads(''.join(''.join(piece) for piece in data))
>>> pprint.pprint(decoded)
[{'count': [[2011, 6], [2012, 0], [2013, 11]],
  'level': 'k',
  'name': 'david',
  'xaxis': [[]],
  'yaxis': [[]]},
 {'count': [[2008, 130],
            [2009, 53],
            [2010, 10],
            [2011, 17],
            [2012, 0],
            [2013, 142]],
  'level': 'n',
  'name': 'marshall',
  'xaxis': [[]],
  'yaxis': [[]]}]
```

At this point `decoded` will be a Python dictionary with your data, if you want to convert it into the complete JSON string you can just `json.dumps()`:

```
>>> json.dumps(decoded)
'[{"count": [[2011, 6], [2012, 0], [2013, 11]], "yaxis": [[]], "name": "david", "xaxis": [[]], "level": "k"}, {"count": [[2008, 130], [2009, 53], [2010, 10], [2011, 17], [2012, 0], [2013, 142]], "yaxis": [[]], "name": "marshall", "xaxis": [[]], "level": "n"}]'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please suggest a bit more looking at the updated question? Thanks.